# How to detect patterns between fields of a distribution in SPSS?

Tags: distributions, spss, pattern-recognition

Suppose I have the following simplified distribution:

```
time | value
1    | 2
2    | 4
3    | 8
4    | 16

1    | 1
2    | 3
3    | 9
4    | 27

1    | 40
2    | 20
3    | 10
4    | 5

1    | 12
2    | 1
3    | 99
4    | 23423
```

These are all part of the same dataset (so one x can have multiple values here, eg. time = 1 corresponds with value = 2,1,40,12). I separated them because the first 3 have an obvious pattern within their slope (2, 3 and 0.5) and the last does not have a pattern in its slope. Time is in days, and the values represent a quantity.

Now, how do I use SPSS to find the elements of a distribution that together form a pattern (any kind of pattern) in their slope? And how can I make it also include elements that almost follow this pattern, but have slight variations (a variation that I can set)?

Any feedback is appreciated. Thanks.

**Update:**

It looks like SPSS is not the best tool for the task. I am interested in the R language however.

If anyone could recommend any books regarding this field of pattern recognition in R, that would be great.

Comment: @Tom, how did you uncover the obvious pattern? For 4 time periods and 4 different values for each period there are $4^4=256$ possible combinations, why did you post only 4 of them? I am asking because I suspect that there might be another variable which indicates how to group the values.

Comment: @mpiktas, I probably missed a lot of patterns too in the above example. I just gave a simple example (it is not my actual data). I made them up while writing this question. I am trying to find patterns between individual fields in a dataset.

Comment: @Tom, so what is your real data look like then?

Comment: @mpiktas it's stock data by date, so basically multiple stocks with certain daily dates with stock prices of each date

Comment: @Tom, so you want to see if stock price has any obvious time trend?

Comment: @mpiktas not in the whole dataset. I want it to combine all possible combinations of each field and test for patterns in the slope for consecutive days (so eg. x=1,2,3 or x=5,6,7), if there is one (or with a slight variation in pattern I can set) I want it to return that combination.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I understand what you are after, but I might be wrong - just to clarify things in advance :)

If you want to find the "distribution" of your data, than [R](http://www.r-project.org/) could do this easily, I have no idea about Spss. Though I am not sure about your are really after distributions, as those would only show the probabilities of certain values in your data series not dealing with the order, `fitdistr` from [MASS](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/MASS/index.html) and `fitdist` from [fitdistrplus](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/fitdistrplus/index.html) package will be your friend. Also, [Vito Ricci's paper](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/contrib/Ricci-distributions-en.pdf) worths reading in the issue available on CRAN.

A small example assuming you have a data table (`data`) with your data, and would like to fit the first columns data to normal distribution:

```
library(fitdistrplus)
fitdist(data[,1],"norm")
```

If you would like to get the "slopes" of the pattern of a data in a row, as I suppose you are really after, than you need to set up some linear models based on your data. I am sure Spss can do the trick also, but in R look for `lm` and `glm` functions. See the manual of the [lm](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/lm.html) to fit linear models.

A small example:

```
# make up a demo dataset from day 1 to day 10 with 10 values
data <- data.frame(time=1:10, data=c(4.17,5.58,5.18,6.11,4.50,4.61,5.17,4.53,5.33,5.14))
```

This would look like:

```
> data
   time data
1     1 4.17
2     2 5.58
3     3 5.18
4     4 6.11
5     5 4.50
6     6 4.61
7     7 5.17
8     8 4.53
9     9 5.33
10   10 5.14
```

And fit a simple model on it:

```
> lm(data)

Call:
lm(formula = data)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)         data  
     4.6613       0.1667
```

Which shows the slope being around 0.16667.

Comment: It is clear to me I should learn R. Do you recommend any books that I could read to learn about pattern recognition in R? I am not just looking for a pattern in my distribution. I'm looking for all patterns that multiple fields of my distribution make up together.

Comment: @Tom: you definitely should :) R has a really great potential if you plan to make complex computations in the future. To learn R, you can find a lot of great books and blogs also in the issue, just to pick up a free one, look for *Statistics with R* by Vincent Zoonekynd (http://zoonek2.free.fr/UNIX/48_R/all.html) and look for  Ch. 11-12 for different kind of models. I have also made up a small collection of useful links in the subject, check it if you wish: http://r.snowl.net/interesting-urls-dealing-with-r/

Comment: @Tom: a better approach could be reading through the answers of *Books for learning the R language* question on SO: http://stackoverflow.com/q/192369/564164